# is there any way to point out or delete useless import in .m file of Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

is there any way to automicly point out or delete useless import in .m file of Objective-C?

Such as my .m file :

```
#import "A.h"
#import "B.h"
#import "C.h"
```

But B.h in my .m file will never be used,is there any way to automicly point out or delete it, just like AppCode IDE.

Comment: There are a few scripts floating around, but there's no official tool, especially not in Xcode.

Comment: @Avi ,can u provide the link of  script, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out here: [Find unused Objective-C imports](https://github.com/dblock/fui)

Use as follows:

Find Unused Classes in a Path

```
fui --path=~/source/project/Name find
```

Delete All Unused Class Files w/ Prompt

```
fui --path=~/source/project/Name delete --perform --prompt
```

*You can also use XCode Plugin for that:*

Use `xcfui` for integration with `XCode` from here: https://github.com/jcavar/xcfui

*Script to find unused imports:*

https://gist.github.com/Orangenhain/7691314

Comment: I know the Fui, Fui can point out which file never be import, but not imported which not used

Comment: Script that takes a ObjC .m file and tries to find unused (or duplicate) import statements by commenting out each #import line in turn and seeing if the project still compiles. You will have to change BUILD_DIR & BUILD_CMD. that already stated in link@SubCycle

Comment: I run this script by " ruby ./import_minimizer.rb ",but it print this error: import_minimizer.rb:15:in `readable?': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
 from import_minimizer.rb:15:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, there is no official XCode tool, but you can do this with different other tools (e.g. with [Fui](https://github.com/dblock/fui))

Comment: I know the Fui, Fui can point out which file never be import, but not imported which not used

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/ has a code inspection feature which finds unused imports and code.

Comment: YES,I know AppCode has this Feature,but what i want is script or source code, not only Feature